# Clicking on a dynamic link with scrapy

Tags: javascript, python, scrapy

I have a clickable link on a dynamically created page, that looks like:

```
<a id="ucResultsGrid_X0A" href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ucResultsGrid$X0A", "", false, "", "webProperty.aspx?dbkey=parkercad&amp;stype=id&amp;sdata=X0A&amp;time=201606062005057&amp;id=X0A", false, true))' style="text-decoration:underline;">View Detail</a>
```

What approach is best to click this link with scrapy?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Scrapy but I can suggest an alternative :-)

Have you looked into an alternative such as [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/)? They provide an example for [Minimal Scraping](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#a-minimal-scraping-script) as well as scraping Google.

Please note, you will need to use either SlimerJS or PhantomJS with CasperJS.